How to search multiple indexes in ELK's kibana UI?
ELKs Kibana UI has a discover tab which allows you to select an index, enter a search phrase, and select a time frame.  The drop down says "Change index Patter", but doesnt allow multi-select, and doesn't allow wild cards.
This is great, but most of the time we want to search across several indexes.
Is there a way to do this?
